# CakePHP Fatal Error class 'L18n' not found

Tags: cakephp

Since this morning I can't get one of my pages working.

The error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'I18n' not found in /home/drukwerk/domains/drukwerkprijsvergelijk.nl/public_html/lib/Cake/basics.php on line 507

I found out this will only happen when I echo a form like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Wenis');
```

When I left my work three days ago it still worked.. now it's broken.
Does somebody ever had a similar problem before?

Comment: Well, what has changed in the last 3 days? You *do* have a revision control system to track that, right? ;-)

Comment: Well, I added my own component, added var $components = 'FileHandlerComponent' to one of my controllers.. thats it.
Now I deleted the lines + the component and it stopped working.

Comment: does  `lib\Cake\I18n\I18n.php` exist?

Comment: Yes checked it already, I found out the problem. Somehow I had a controller inside my modelfolder.. also the L1on.php from the cake lib disappeared... we don't know how.

Ayways, it's working again! Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your app cache app/tmp/cache make sure you really did not change anything (I hope you use git, svn or something else). Make sure the core was not changed or updated - maybe by someone else in your team.

Also there should be some trace that shows you from where exactly the fatal error comes from. Line 507 is the end result but what was called before? I suggest you to use xdebug.

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to fix the problem (deleting cache), line 507 tells cake to translate your content if you give translations in some files (I don't use it tho).

Comment: I'm aware of that but asking for a stack trace. Cake and xdebug should get you that. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace

Comment: I fixed it bro, thanks for your help ;)! Answer is inside comment up from here.